# Vue 3 - Tabbing between multiple instances of a component

Tags: vue.js

How do I make multiple instances of the same component and tab between them?

With this code my ChartComponent is the same object on every tab.  I want a different instance per tab.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted, computed } from "vue";
import _ from "lodash";
import ChartComponent from "../components/ChartComponent.vue";

const tabs = ref([] as Object[]);

const activeTabId = ref(1);

const activeTab = computed(() => _.find(tabs.value, { id: activeTabId.value }));

let nextTabId = 1;

const addTab = (symbol: string) => {
  tabs.value.push({
    id: nextTabId++,
    symbol: symbol,
    component: ChartComponent,
  });
};

onMounted(() => {
  addTab("AAA");
  addTab("BBB");
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="activeTab?.component" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure what's the case `<component :key="activeTab?.id"` could be what you need

Comment: @EstusFlask Not sure how that would work here.  Can you show an example?

Comment: Literally `<component :key="activeTab?.id" :is="activeTab?.component"  />`. If this doesn't solve the problem consider what it is and explaining your case further